# .pipe(takeUntil) is listening when it is not supposed to

Tags: rxjs, pipe, fork-join, takeuntil

We are using .pipe(takeUntil) in the logincomponent.ts. What I need is, it should get destroyed after successful log in and the user is on the landing page. However, the below snippet is being called even when the user is trying to do other activity and hitting submit on the landing page should load different page but the result of submit button is being overridden and taken back to the landing page.

```
enter code hereforkJoin({
  flag: this.auth
    .getEnvironmentSettings('featureEnableQubeScan')
    .pipe(take(1)),
  prefs: this.auth.preferences.pipe(take(1)),
}).subscribe(
  (result: any) => {
    this.qubeScanEnabled = result.flag.featureEnableQubeScan;
    this.userPrefs = result.prefs;
    // check to see if we're authed (but don't keep listening)
     this.auth.authed
      .pipe(takeUntilComponentDestroyed(this))
      .subscribe((payload: IJwtPayload) => {
        if (payload) {
           this.auth.accountO
            .pipe(takeUntilComponentDestroyed(this))
            .subscribe((account: IAccount) => {
                if (this.returnUrl) {
                  this.router.navigateByUrl(this.returnUrl);
                } else {
                      this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
        }
);

 ngOnDestroy() {}
```

Custom Code:

```
    export function takeUntilComponentDestroyed(component: OnDestroy) {
  const componentDestroyed = (comp: OnDestroy) => {
    const oldNgOnDestroy = comp.ngOnDestroy;
    const destroyed$ = new ReplaySubject<void>(1);
    comp.ngOnDestroy = () => {
      oldNgOnDestroy.apply(comp);
      destroyed$.next(undefined);
      destroyed$.complete();
    };
    return destroyed$;
  };

  return pipe(
    takeUntil(componentDestroyed(component))
  );
}
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.
Versions:
rxjs: 6.5.5
Angular:10.0.8
Thanks

Comment: Add take(1) operator, if you stop listening after first stream.

Comment: my understanding is ".pipe(takeUntilComponentDestroyed(this))" would take care of this. Correct me if i am wrong. Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful to create a StackBlitz that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Kind suggestion, get rid of the nested subscriptions.If you do so you can remove the custom operator and simply use the common `takeUntil(unsubscribe$)` approach.

Comment: `takeUntil()` is waiting for destroyed$ to emit and I'm not sure `undefined` counts as an emission. Maybe try `destroyed$.next(1);` (Change the declaration as well) and see if you have better luck.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a first pass at creating a stream that doesn't nest subscriptions and continues to have the same semantics. The major difference is that I can move `takeUntilComponentDestroyed` to the end of the stream and lets the unsubscibes filter backup the chain. (It's a bit cleaner and you don't run the same code twice every time through)

It's a matter of taste, but flattening operators are a bit easier to follow for many.

```
enter code hereforkJoin({
  flag: this.auth
    .getEnvironmentSettings('featureEnableQubeScan')
    .pipe(take(1)),
  prefs: this.auth.preferences.pipe(take(1)),
}).pipe(
  tap((result: any) => {
    this.qubeScanEnabled = result.flag.featureEnableQubeScan;
    this.userPrefs = result.prefs;
  }),
  mergeMap((result: any) => this.auth.authed),
  filter((payload: IJwtPayload) => payload != null),
  mergeMap((payload: IJwtPayload) => this.auth.accountO),
  takeUntilComponentDestroyed(this)
).subscribe((account: IAccount) => {        
  if (this.returnUrl) {
    this.router.navigateByUrl(this.returnUrl);
  } else {
    this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
  }
});
```

This function doesn't create another inner stream (`destroyed$`). This way is a bit more back to the basics so it should be easier to debug if you're not getting the result you want.

```
export function takeUntilComponentDestroyed<T>(comp: OnDestroy): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T> {
  return input$ => new Observable(observer => {
    const sub = input$.subscribe({
      next: val => observer.next(val),
      complete: () => observer.complete(),
      error: err => observer.error(err)
    });
    const oldNgOnDestroy = comp.ngOnDestroy;
    comp.ngOnDestroy = () => {
      oldNgOnDestroy.apply(comp);
      sub.unsubscribe();
      observer.complete();
    };
    return { unsubscribe: () => sub.unsubscribe() };
  });
}
```